# Immortal process in Windows; no way to kill it

Tags: windows, qt, windows-7, process, kill

I am writing a normal, innocent C++/Qt program in Windows 7/MinGW.

It is the second time in two days that after closing the program the executable remains among the active processes, and there is no way to kill it (I try both from the command line and from Windows Task Manager).

One inconvenience is that I cannot re-link my code, because the binary code cannot be overwritten, being running.

Comment: Did you try pressing the Power Off button? (Hint: this is off-topic here.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Why off topic? Isn't this a question about software development issues?

Comment: at least partly off-topic. While you ask this question in the context of developing an application, the question is actually "how do I kill a process", which is a general software-related question, and as such, it belongs on [SU].

Comment: @H2CO3: you are partly right. However, consider that: 1. I know how to kill a normal application; 2. This application is developed by myself; 3. This application could not be killed because running in the debugger; 4. The debugger is a development tool used by developers; 5. Not all developers (or at least one of them, me) know that the debugger can prevent from killing an executable under its control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that the executable was running under the control of the debugger, and this protected the process against any attempt to kill it. Stopping it through the debugger has been successful.

I did not know that the debugger could shield a process from any external attempt to kill it so well...

Comment: It would have been absolutely splendid for this question and answer to be ported to superuser. That's where it belongs.

Comment: Or maybe to ServerFault? Is it possible to move this Q&A somehow?

Comment: I had Visual Studio opened and it could not write to the .exe file ot my apllication. There was an instance of it running on a "zombie state" when i saw processes in Task Manager. I tried to kill it in with right-click/End process in there, but it displays an "Access denied" message. I also tried with command line's taskkill, but it returned me the text 
"ERROR: The process "App.exe" with PID 19644 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task."
So, closing Visual Studio solved the problem, because after that, the process 19644 does not exist any more.